# Silence Output From Azure SQL Powershell Commands

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have a Powershell script to copy our production database to our test environment as well as associated clean up activities. I'd like to clean up the information outputted for the user to the console, and am having trouble figuring out clean up the error messages I get from my Az.sql commands.

One of my first actions is to attempt to see if a temporary database exists for and needs to be cleaned up

```
#clean up existing
$availableDatabase = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $TestResourceGroup -ServerName $TestServerName -DatabaseName $TestTempDatabaseName
```

If it's not there I'll get the following error output in the console:

```
Remove-AzSqlDatabase : The Resource 
'Microsoft.Sql/servers/xxxx/databases/reap_prod_copy_2' under resource group 'xxxx' was not found.
At C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\reap-replace-test.ps1:17 char:1
+ Remove-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $TestResourceGroup -ServerNam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzSqlDatabase], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Cmdlet.RemoveAzureSqlDatabase
```

I would like to capture this output and provide a simple "Does not exist" message instead, or even just completely move on without any output.  I've tried putting "| Out-Null" on the end, but that doesn't seem to effect the output in any way.  Any insights?

Comment: Have you tried a try/catch block with the `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter with `Remove-AzSqlDatabase`?

Comment: Using a combination of -ErrorAction Stop/SilentlyContinue and | Out-Null it looks like I can achieve what I wanted...thanks for the heads up on those common parameters!

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `if(){}else{}` statement to do that, try the script as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$availableDatabase = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $TestResourceGroup -ServerName $TestServerName -DatabaseName $TestTempDatabaseName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($availableDatabase){

    Remove-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $TestResourceGroup -ServerName $TestServerName -DatabaseName $TestTempDatabaseName
    Write-Host "Remove the sql db" $TestTempDatabaseName

}else{
    Write-Host "The sql db" $TestTempDatabaseName "does not exist" 

    }
```

**Test result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue was the missing link for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try catch` block to capture the exception.

```
try {
    #clean up existing
    $availableDatabase = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $TestResourceGroup -ServerName $TestServerName -DatabaseName $TestTempDatabaseName
} 
catch {
    Write-Host "Does not exist"
    $availableDatabase = $null
}

if ($availableDatabase -ne $null) {
    # ... Do stuff with database
}
```

The above will execute everything in the `try` block and if it encounters an error of any type it will execute everything in the `catch` block. The `if` statement may or may not be necessary depending on implementation.

See [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6)

**Note:** The above `catch` block will catch ***any*** error, regardless of if it was caused by a missing table or not. It is generally a best practice to include a specific exception type after `catch` when possible to avoid silencing unrelated errors that may need to be fixed.

Comment: This was actually the first method I tried but for some reason it doesn't seem to go to the catch when error occurs? It still throws the error in console and doesn't print the Write-Host output...

Comment: Could you post the code you tried in your question?